# How to access ip_address from inventory for a specific host?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-template

Inventory looks like:

```
[host-1]
h1    ansible_ssh_private_key_file="*/*/*"    ansible_host=a.b.c.d
h2    ansible_ssh_private_key_file="*/*/*"    ansible_host=a.b.c.t

[host-2]
h3    ansible_ssh_private_key_file="*/*/*"    ansible_host=a.b.c.r
```

I want to ***use ansible_host oh 'h2' in templates*** but I am getting **ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable** error. How to resolve it?

I have already tried these:

```
1. "{{hostvars['host-2'][h2][ansible_host]}}"
2. "{{hostvars[host-2][h2][ansible_host]}}"
3. "{{hostvars['host-2'][h2].ansible_host}}"
4. "{{hostvars[groups['host-2'][h2]].ansible_host}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax

```
"{{ hostvars['h2']['ansible_host'] }}"
```

, or

```
"{{ hostvars.h2.ansible_host }}"
```

Hint: Take a look at `"{{ hostvars }}"` and `"{{ groups }}"`.

Answer (score 1):

Please take it as a hint:

```
- name: host
  debug: msg="{{hostvars['h2']['ansible_host']}}"
```